# Event Handling in JavaFX

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx

I am confused all about the subject of event handling.

I am trying to implement a game. I already wrote the game logic separately, and the GUI (on JavaFX).

Below is some sample code; What can I do so that the `updateScoresLabel()` method will run whenever the `setScore(...)` method is executed?

```
public class MyGameLogic
{
    private int scores=0;

    public void setScore(int scores)
    {
        this.scores=scores;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return scores;
    }

}



public class JustAGUIExample
{
    Label scoresLabel;
    MyGameLogic gameLogic;

    public void updateScoresLabel()
    {
        this.scoresLabel=gameLogic.getScore();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Event handling is handled with callback objects typically implementing some action interface. Beyond that, you'll need to show what you have so far and where you're getting stuck. Or, [read more on the topic here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post.. 
I should put a lot listeners in my project.. but I have no idea what to do. I read a lot of stuff. 
I am really confused because I was used to do it easily on C#, but now I'm lost:/

Comment: Sorry. For anybody to be able to help you, you need to provide more code. Preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user1994339 *"but I have no idea what to do"* That's why I posted that link, so you can start to have an idea. And again, this is still  vague. In the situation you posted, you may have to re-think the design, and/or implement an [event aggregator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52810/Event-Aggregator-with-Specialized-Listeners), or look in to the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for notifying the UI of model changes.

Comment: This question in it's current form is actually pretty good and doesn't deserve the number of downvotes it has received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Use Binding Instead of Event Handlers*

You don't need an event handler to accomplish a label update when a model change occurs.

You can [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) your label property to your model property, then when you change the model, the label will update automatically.

Adapting the code from your question to use binding.

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MyGameLogic {
    private IntegerProperty scores = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    public void setScore(int scores) {
        this.scores.set(scores);
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return scores.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty scoreProperty() {
        return scores;
    }
}

class JustAGUIExample {
    private Label scoresLabel;
    private MyGameLogic gameLogic;

    public JustAGUIExample() {
        scoresLabel.textProperty().bind(
            gameLogic.scoreProperty().asString()
        );
    }
}
```

There are extensive examples of this kind of binding strategy in this [JavaFX tic-tac-toe game example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901).

*For more complex logic use a ChangeListener*

Let's say you also wanted to play a victory sound when the score changes, you could use something like this:

```
class JustAGUIExample {
    private Label scoresLabel;
    private MyGameLogic gameLogic;
    private AudioClip levelUpAudio = new AudioClip("levelup.mp3");

    public JustAGUIExample() {
        scoresLabel.textProperty().bind(
            gameLogic.scoreProperty().asString()
        );

        gameLogic.scoreProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                levelUpAudio.play();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) is kind of like an event listener for property changes.  But I only say kind of because in JavaFX events are there own separate things and are usually reserved for GUI system events like mouse clicks, window resizing notification, touchpad swipes, etc.

Using Java 8 the syntax is nicer:

```
gameLogic.scoreProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    levelUpAudio.play()
);
```

*Tutorial on Event Handling in Java*

Even though you don't really need event handling for the sample from your question, you can read up on the [Oracle JavaFX event handling tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) to find out what events really are and how they work.

*My Thoughts On Swing Based Suggestions*

As you are writing a JavaFX program please disregard any suggestions which relate to event handling in Swing.  Instead, learn to do this stuff in a JavaFX way or you will just confuse yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot jewelsea!!
Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI to run an event, the class must implement ActionListener. From this the method actionPerformed must be added to that class.

Here is a sample implementation of that

```
 //Run, help, and about are all buttons on this frame
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == run){ //Check if the event was the run button being pressed
        //Run the "run" program
    }else if(e.getSource() == about){ //Check if the event was the about button being pressed
        //Open welcome
    }else if(e.getSource() == help){ //Check if the event was the help button being pressed
        //Have the help screen appear
    }
}
```